# Using Selenium IDE how can I mouseover elements in bootstrap scripted UIs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selenium, mouseover, selenium-ide, onmouseover

I am trying to use mouseover to hover over an element in a site using Bootstrap (I've tried with buttons, or simply img classes) but no luck. Here's my element that I want to mouseOver on for which some content gets displayed (which I want to validate) on doing so. thanks

```
<span class="label-info form-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Information" data-content="The data that needs to be verified">
```

I tried the below which didn't work for me:

```
<tr> 
  <td>mouseOver</td>
  <td>xpath of element location mentioned above</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

See google example below when mouseOver over googlesearch button then button is blur.

```
      <tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>https://www.google.co.in/</td>
<td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>mouseOver</td>
<td>id=gbqfba</td>
<td>Google Search</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>verifyTextPresent</td>
<td>I'm Feeling Lucky</td>
<td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>verifyTextPresent</td>
<td>Google Search</td>
<td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
<td>mouseOut</td>
<td>id=gbqfba</td>
<td>Google Search</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is bootstrap css and I'm not sure how to use mouseover for bootstrap as it doesn't work for its elements. Any ideas?