# Selenium IDE - Select Googles Autofill Options

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am attempting to write a test that selects the first auto complete option in Google and selects the "I feel Lucky" link.  My first thought was to select the search bar, then scroll to the first result and tab to the correct link.  However I can't seem to get the the focus on the search bar.

Bellow is what I have so far: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PBRn.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be more concrete with what you need. Please provide some part of your code and/or errors you've received to improve your questions. Please explain the picture you set.

Comment: At the moment my goal is to be able to type a value into Google using selenium IDE, scroll down and select the "I feel lucky" link on one of the auto fill options that show up.  For example:

http://i.imgur.com/4v9gRgf.png

However right now I'm having trouble getting the focus on the actual search bar.  I tried something along the lines of:

<tr>
 <td>focus</td>
 <td>id =lst-ib</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>keyPress</td>
 <td>id=lst-ib</td>
 <td>40</td>
</tr>

I don't get any errors, and the test passes, it just won't select the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like google uses href="#ifl" as the identifier for the I feel lucky. You can find this out by mousing over whatever you want to use, right click it and select "Inspect element" while in google chrome. It will bring up the hmtl so you can see what the actual element is named.

```
public void IFL()
{
        driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl";
        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[id*='lst-ib']"));
        element.SendKeys("Hello W");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var luck = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[href*='#ifl']"));
        IWebElement ifl = luck[0];
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.MoveToElement(ifl).Build().Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ifl.Click();
}
```

We select all of the "I feel Lucky" elements, then pick the first one (which is the first link), move the mouse to that location, then click.

It isn't the cleanest way to do it but it should do what you need it to.

EDIT:

I see now you're using the IDE you should be able to use MouseOver href=#ifl then click.

Comment: Actually [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444659/using-selenium-ide-how-can-i-mouseover-elements-in-bootstrap-scripted-uis) looks pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with to search for the term "first" and select first drop down option.
Start at http://google.com

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=lst-ib</td>
    <td>first</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//ul[@role='listbox']/li</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//ul[@role='listbox']/li/div</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

For me there is no i'm feeling lucky option at this point. But if there was that'd be easy. Otherwise you select the first search result:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//h2[text()='Search Results']/..//ol/div//li//a</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```